# Multiplying Values of Two HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap

If I have two `HashMap`s, `hm1` and `hm2`, how can I iterate through the two and multiply the two values together at each point in the two `HashMap`s and sum the total? They are both ordered identically, so I don't need to worry about the keys, just the values.

The data is in the form

```
hm1 = 
(A, 3)
(B, 4)
(C, 7)

hm2 =
(A, 4)
(B, 6)
(C, 3)
```

then I want to do something like this but obviously this code is incorrect because I'm only iterating through hm1.

```
double sum = 0.00;
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> hm : hm1.entrySet()) {
    sum += hm1.getValue() * hm2.getValue();
}
```

So I would basically loop through and do:

```
1st iteration: Sum = 0 + 3*4
2nd Iteration: Sum = 12 + 4*6
3rd iteration: Sum = 36 + 7*3
Exit Loop:
Sum = 57
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: HashMaps are unordered, so you would have to worry about the keys.

Comment: Ok, thanks How would I implement this then?

Comment: Though a `LinkedHashMap` would preserve iteration order

Comment: @WilliamPrice: Unless the two maps don't have the exact same keys inserted in the exact same order. Then the two stream won't line up.

Comment: @Thilo It's not clear from the question that the keys are necessarily required to match, or if simply pairing entries from equivalently sized maps is sufficient.  Some clarification from the OP would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try writing some code?

Comment: It says "they are both ordered identically". Presumably that is important.

Comment: Important, yes, but not necessarily unambiguous.  (Just playing devil's advocate.  I can use two LHMs and have them be "ordered identically" by insertion order rather than by key.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the key from your iteration over the first map to get the value for the second one:

```
double sum = 0.00;
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> hm : hm1.entrySet()) {
   double hm2Value = hm2.get(hm.getKey());
   sum += hm.getValue() * hm2Value;
}
```

Note that this only works if both maps have the same keys. If keys are missing in either, then you have to think about how to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks, the keys are the same in both in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the two HashMaps have equal amount of entries, and that all the entries have the same corresponding key, then a solid way to aquire the sum would be like this:

```
double sum = 0;

/* iterate through all the keys in hm1 */
/* order doesn't matter */
for (String key : hm1.keySet()) {
    double value1 = hm1.get(key);
    double value2 = hm2.get(key);
    sum += value1 * value2;
}
```

Comment: [Thilo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27309373/2390644) is slightly better as it iterates over the `entrySet` method to eliminate an extra call to `hm1.get(key)`.

Comment: @WilliamPrice I would argue that this method is easier to understand and prettier.

Comment: @WilliamPrice Thilo's answer is worse because it's less readable.  Hard to read code might not cost as many CPU cycles but it does cost your boss more money.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: That's because I tried to keep as close as possible to the code in the original question. I would write it like Olavi, too.

Comment: @Thilo Good of you to say so.  Infact, I'm gonna stalk you until I find a Q or A of yours that I can upvote just because I like your attitude :)

Answer (score 0):

Java Version 8, you can use Stream API:

```
    Map<String, Double> hm1 = new HashMap<String, Double>() {{
        put("A", 3.0);
        put("B", 4.0);
        put("C", 7.0);
    }};

    Map<String, Double> hm2 = new HashMap<String, Double>() {{
        put("A", 4.0);
        put("B", 6.0);
        put("C", 3.0);
    }};

    double sum = hm1.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> hm2.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
        .map(entry -> entry.getValue() * hm2.get(entry.getKey()))
        .mapToDouble(value -> value)
        .sum();
```